# Request timeout in amazon

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have changed `/etc/hosts` settings and run the following command to apply them:

`ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up`

But something broke in the middle and now I am logged out of the session and can't log back in - pinging my IP returns request timeout.

How do I repair this? It's amazon ec3.

Comment: restart the instance from the AWS console

Comment: If rebooting doesn't work you could always try executing an ec2 run command from the Amazon Console to undo the previous changes to the /etc/hosts file. Obviously you would have to write the script to do this and execute through an ec2 run command. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/